# Функция imagepng() не работает с переменными

Tags: php, gd

Подскажите, почему код:

```
imagepng($im,'image.png');
```

работает, а

```
$file='image.png';
imagepng($im,$file);
```

нет? Спасибо.

Comment: $im это и есть ресурс изображения созданный imagecreatetruecolor(). Проблема в том, что функция работает только если параметр пути задан константой.

Answer (score 0):

Из документации PHP

> Ресурс изображения, возвращаемый одной из функций создания изображений, например, такой как imagecreatetruecolor().

Следовательно, первым параметром должен передаваться не файл, а именно ресурс.
Если я вас правильно понял